# Django Rest Framework Doesn't escape Html Entity Problem

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I wrote the django blog and api.

When i started the postman and then wrote the api url it returns correct values except content i have issue with content content is returning &ouml . It's turkish charset &ouml=ö
How can i fix this problem ?

api/serializers.py:

```py
class MakaleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Yazar = serializers.CharField(source="Yazar.username")
    class Meta:
        model = Makale
        fields = ('__all__')
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['İçerik'] = strip_tags(instance.İçerik)
        return data
```

api/views.py:

```py
class MakaleRudView(APIView):
   def get(self, request):
       makale = Makale.objects.all()
       serializer = MakaleSerializer(makale , many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)
```

and the postman or drf(Django Rest Framework returns :

```
    {
        "id": 26,
        "Yazar": "gorkem",
        "Başlık": "Atatürk'ün Samsuna Çıkışı 2",
        "İçerik": "Atat&uuml;rk&#39;&uuml;n Samsuna &ccedil;ıkışı sırasında T&uuml;rkiye Cumhuriyeti&#39;nin",
        "Olusturma_Tarihi": "2020-05-29T09:10:43.874477+03:00",
        "makal_resim": null
    },
```

Comment: How can i fix it ?

Comment: Given your use of `strip_tags`, I'd venture the guess that you're also *HTML-encoding* the string *somewhere*. It's probably stored like this already in the database…?!